# python implementation or launcher able to run both 3.x and 2.x code

Tags: python

A python implementation able to run both 3.x and 2.x code would be quite convenient.

[PyPy is planning this for the future](http://pypy.org/py3donate.html), but currently it only supports v2.x.

As alternative, is there any wrapper launcher that is able to perform on-the-fly code conversion (like 2to3 and 3to2)?

E.g. for running python3 code on python2 i've written this:

```
python -c "from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals; execfile(\"$1\");"
```

Answer (score 1):

For code that you need to run on python 2 and 3 there is the [six library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) with documentation [here](https://pythonhosted.org/six/).

It handles things like all of your imports but also copes with things like name changes between a lot of the standard library items for you.

Also [PEP 397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) deals with creating a python launcher for windows that is [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) aware so python scripts that start with `#! /usr/bin/python2` would be launched under python 2, etc.

The [Python 3.3](https://wingware.com/psupport/python-manual/3.4/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-397-python-launcher-for-windows) installer *and later* includes an implementation of this that will allow `py filename` to launch the required python for processing the script, *(just like Linux, etc.)*.

You can also use the `py` launcher with command line overrides such as:

- `py -2 somefile.py3` *launch a python 3 file under python 2*
- `py -3 somefile.py` *force latest python 3 to run a file even if the shebang says to use python 2*
- `py -2.6-32 somefile.py` *force the use of python 2.6 32 bit assuming it is installed*